# Any idea why this piece of PHP code is making my script hang?

Tags: php

thanks for your time in reading this. I am not a programmer but with my limited skills I have been able to determine that this function which is called at the beginning of almost every page is making our store POS script fail. When we goto our url for this PHP application we get only a blank page. When the call to this function is commented out, the pages load just fine.

The interesting thing to note is that no changes have been made to our code and it has been in use for over 3 years. Just stopped working a couple days ago and our webhost is useless. They haven't been able to tell me if there were any changes made to our server environment so I don't know where to start looking for information. My colleague suspects they may have changed the version of PHP that is in use, though I don't know which version might have preceded the one listed here.

Server Info
-Apache version     2.2.29

-PHP version    5.4.33

-MySQL version  5.5.37-cll

-Architecture   x86_64

-Operating system   linux

```
// new version for SEO htaccess short url's
Function MakeSecure(){
    if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on"){
        $URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $strSiteLocation = "https://" . str_replace("/","",DOMAIN) . $URI;
        header("Location: " . $strSiteLocation );
    }
}
```

Comment: @l'L'l could be a `const`

Comment: Have you checked which value `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` has? According to the docs any non-empty value (not just "on") should indicate the protocol is https.

Comment: Set this at the top of the file to show all errors PHP throws. `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`. Please note that you should preferably do this in a development enviroment, and not on live websites.

Comment: @Bono I added that to the first file that loads up and still get a blank page. Does not seem to make a difference. Also looked through the code to find perhaps another instance of `error_reporting` that might counter this addition. No effect.

Comment: That's peculiar. Make sure you put it in the file that shows up in the url in your browser. Also try Bart's suggestion. If you don't know how to show it; do `echo $_SERVER['HTTPS']`; or `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTPS']);`

Comment: @Bart I am sorry I don't understand how I can check. My programming skills are really not skills at all, more like scraps of understanding from working with HTML eons ago. I am just an employee here trying to get it back up to normal. Could you give me a step by step how I can help you check if this is the case? Thanks!

Comment: `string(2) "on" 
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/ros/public_html/tiger2/login.php:5) in /home/ros/public_html/tiger2/functions/session.class.php on line 3`

This is now what I get when adding your `var_dump`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So PHP was upgraded from 5.3 to 5.4 and the common class was passing variables by reference which is disallowed in 5.4. changed a line in the common class from

`$cp = fsockopen (SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT, &$errno, &$errstr, 1);`

to

`$cp = fsockopen (SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT, $errno, $errstr, 1);`

now the website is loading fine. Thanks to all who weighed in!

Comment: You should mark your own answer as accepted, to close off the question.

You should also find a new webhost if they're going to be upgrading your platform with no notice!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've set DOMAIN as a constant somewhere else, it's not going to redirect anywhere. Since you said this is at the top of your code, I suspect this is the case.

To confirm this, replace that final `header()` call with a call to `echo()` (output to browser) or `error_log()` (output to your web server log file) instead. This will show you where it's trying to redirect you; I think it won't be a valid URL.

Comment: in our `settings.php` there is line 15 `define("DOMAIN", "domain.com/");` when I changed header to echo, I wasn't able to get any output. I would like to reiterate that this code has been working for over 3 years with no issues or changes made to instigate this. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Yet you said the page worked fine when you commented out this code? Since there's three lines of code and two of them are simple string manipulation, the `header` call seems like the problem. Update your question to include the actual code on the page, showing where this is being called in context.

Comment: That function is called on multiple pages so while taking it out fixes the issue on one page, any link you click to move to another page results in a blank screen. This is not something that was recently added, I was only commenting out sections of code following the chain starting with index.php to try to figure out what was creating this issue. Please bear with me as I have said I am not qualified to troubleshoot this myself. It would be a lot of code to post because its like a chain and 4-5 pages are interacting here. Is it appropriate to post 300 lines of code?

Comment: You can always post a pastebin link. What are you commenting out? The call to `MakeSecure()` on each page? Try commenting out all the lines in the function instead, and then add them back in one by one. I still think the header function is the only thing that could be causing a problem.

Comment: See the resolution below @miken32. Thanks for your help, it led me to find where the issue was!